# Simplifying my Eclipse regex

Tags: regex

So, I'm fairly new to regex. That being said, I'm looking for help. I've got this regex to do what I want, but this is as simple as I can make it with my current understanding.

`(\w+\s*?\w+\s*?\-*?/*?\w+)\s*?(\(\w+\))`

What this needs to match are the following configurations of strings:

```
word
word word
word-word
word/word
word word/word
word word/LL
word word (word)
word-word word/word
```

I kind of feel like I'm abusing `*?` but I saw an example that used that and it seemed to do what I needed. I've also seen that just `*` will do the same?  Or just `?`? Anyway there it is. Thanks in advance!

Also, the grouping is there because this regex is actually significantly longer with other groups. Please keep that in mind. I need the group to still work with others (4 in total).

EDIT:  Sorry everyone. I'm actually trying to convert text being copy pasted from a pdf into python syntax using the built in find/replace (using regex) in the Eclipse IDE. That's why I didn't specify what I was using. I thought it was just plain ol' regex.

Also, my current regex works perfectly. What I'm asking for here is a lesson on simplicity (and the `*` and `?` better explained). I just felt my current regex was long and ugly.

Comment: There can be subtle differences between regex syntax and functionality  in different languages. Which one are we talking about here?

Comment: Please also specify which strings you *don't* want to match. `.*` is the simplest pattern that matches all those you've specified, but I presume you don't want that.

Comment: Yes, and also describe in English exactly what you want to match as well.

Comment: will also match `"word(word)"` ... and also `"anyword-----------------------------------------                          (B)"` is it supposed to do that?

Comment: If you want a parser, write a parser.

Comment: Assuming your using Python by looking at your history, this will possibly work. `[A-Za-z]+(?:[ -\/][A-Za-z]+|[ ()])+`

Comment: Why is my question voted down? I feel like this is a perfectly valid question. That and I didn't realize that there were multiple forms of regex. I edited my post as soon as I saw the comments. Please correct your votes if this applies.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I have to be honest - being new to regex I didn't even think about this. The following in my string (which isn't shown above) is always either a single capitol letter, or the word 'Var.'.  It makes me laugh, but I think what you've suggested might actually just be what I should have done. I feel really silly.

Answer (score 2):

`?` after other RegEx quantifiers makes them reluctant.  Meaning that they will match input only when the remainder of the RegEx has not been able to match.

The reluctant `?` is superfluous when the set of characters it applies to has no common character with the following set.  For example in:

```
[0-9]*?[A-Z]
```

there is no way `[A-Z]` will match unless all previous `[0-9]`s have been matched.  Then why make `[0-9]*` reluctant?  On the contrary, make it greedy by removing the `?`.

```
[0-9]*[A-Z]
```

There is a second case where `?` is abused.  For example, you know that certain text contains, say, a colon followed an uppercase word.  There are no other possible occurrences of a colon.

```
.*?:[A-Z]+
```

would do the job.  Hoevever,

```
[^:]*:[A-Z]+
```

represents better the fact that a colon will always initiate what you want to match.  In this case, we "created" the first condition (of character commonality) by realizing that, in fact, there never was need for one.  IOW that we never needed a `.*` matching also `:`s, but just `[^:]*`.

I'm reluctant to use the reluctant operator because sometimes it tends to obscure patterns instead of clarify them and also because performance implications, both thanks to the fact that it increases the level of backtracking enormously (and without a reason).

Applying these principles,

```
(\w+\s*\w+\s*\-*/*\w+)\s*(\(\w+\))
```

seems a better option.  Also, at some point you use `\-*/*`.  It's hard to know what you really want without as many counter-examples as (positive) examples (and this is extremely important while developing and testing any RegEx!), but do you really want to accept perhaps many `-`s followed by perhaps many `/`s?  My impression is that what you are looking for is one `-` or one `/` or one space.  `[ \-/]` would do much better.  Or perhaps `\s*[\-/]?\s*` if you want to accept multiple spaces, even before and/or after the `[\-/]`

```
(\w+\s*\w+\s*[\-/]?\s*\w+)\s*(\(\w+\))
```

See [the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)  on Regular Expressions to find out more.

Comment: The Eclipse IDE offers suggestions for its find/replace regex. `*?` was specifically listed as "Matches 0 or 1 instances". That's my reasoning for using the `*?` (and it worked, to boot). Perhaps it's different than normal?

Comment: That's when used immediately after a character set. When used after a quantifier (`*`, `+`, or another `?`), it makes it reluctant. Eclipse uses Java RegExe's so I'll add to the answer a pointer to Java documentation.

Answer (score 0):

p.s.w.g was correct in pointing out that (.*) is the simplest form of what I needed. The other 3 grouping of my regular expression are specific enough that this works. Thank you p.s.w.g.

PS still don't know why I was down-voted

Comment: Probably because your question seems too basic.  I disagree.  Or at least with downvoting on this criterion.  This prompted me to post something in Meta. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193723/231202